# Interconnecting tables on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am a newbie here.

I am using PostgreSQL to manipulate lots of data in my specific field of research. Unfortunately, I am encountering a problem that is not allowing me to continue my analysis. I tried to simplify my problem to clearly illustrate it.

Let's suppose I have a table called "Buyers" with those data:
[table_buyers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFmR2.png)

The buyers can make ONLY ONE purchase in each store or none. There are three stores and there a table for each one. Just like below:

[table_store1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN2oX.png)

[table_store2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFJwM.png)

[table_store3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wvsF.png)

To create the tables, I am using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE public.buyer
(
ID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name text NOT NULL, 
phone text NOT NULL
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
;

CREATE TABLE public.Store1
(
ID_buyer integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
total_order numeric NOT NULL, 
total_itens integer NOT NULL
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
;


CREATE TABLE public.Store2
(
ID_buyer integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
total_order numeric NOT NULL, 
total_itens integer NOT NULL
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
;


CREATE TABLE public.Store3
(
ID_buyer integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
total_order numeric NOT NULL, 
total_itens integer NOT NULL
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
;
```

To add the information on the tables, I am using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO buyer (ID, name, phone) VALUES
    (1, 'Alex', 88888888),
    (2, 'Igor', 77777777),
    (3, 'Mike', 66666666);

INSERT INTO Store1 (ID_buyer, total_order, total_itens) VALUES
    (1, 87.45, 8),
    (2, 14.00, 3),
    (3, 12.40, 4);

INSERT INTO Store2 (ID_buyer, total_order, total_itens) VALUES
    (1, 785.12, 7),
    (2, 9874.21, 25);

INSERT INTO Store3 (ID_buyer, total_order, total_itens) VALUES
    (2, 45.87, 1);
```

As all the tables are interconnected by buyer's ID, I wish I could have a query that generates an output just like this:
[desired output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNBjA.png).

Please, note that if the buyer did not buy anything in a store, I must print '0'.

I know this is an easy task, but unfortunately, I have been failing on accomplish it.

Using the 'AND' logical operator, I tried the following code to accomplish this task:

```
SELECT 
  buyer.id, 
  buyer.name, 
  store1.total_order, 
  store2.total_order, 
  store3.total_order
FROM 
  public.buyer, 
  public.store1, 
  public.store2, 
  public.store3
WHERE 
  buyer.id = store1.id_buyer AND
  buyer.id = store2.id_buyer AND
  buyer.id = store3.id_buyer;
```

But, obviously, it just returned 'Igor' as this was the only buyer that have bought items on all three stores ([print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDXWE.png)).

Then, I tried the 'OR' logical operator, just like the following code:

```
SELECT 
  buyer.id, 
  buyer.name, 
  store1.total_order, 
  store2.total_order, 
  store3.total_order
FROM 
  public.buyer, 
  public.store1, 
  public.store2, 
  public.store3
WHERE 
  buyer.id = store1.id_buyer OR
  buyer.id = store2.id_buyer OR
  buyer.id = store3.id_buyer;
```

But then, it returns 12 lines with wrong values ([print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L7UZ.png)).

Clearly, my mistake is about not considering that 'Buyers' don't have to on all three stores on my code. I just can't correct it on my own, can you please help me?

I appreciate a lot for an answer that can light up my way. Thanks a lot!

Tips about how I can search for this issue are very welcome as well!

Comment: You mention that you failed to accomplish the task. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried 'AND' and "OR" logical operators, but I am pretty sure this is not the right way. As I am not much familiar with PostgreSQL and computing is not my main background, I am finding this task pretty complicated.

Comment: @djkern, I just uploaded this question to better understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I doubt that this is the final answer for you, but its a start

```
SELECT 
  buyer.id, 
  buyer.name, 
  COALESCE( gb_store1.total_orders, 0 ) as store1_total, 
  COALESCE( gb_store2.total_orders, 0 ) as store2_total, 
  COALESCE( gb_store3.total_orders, 0 ) as store3_total
FROM
  public.buyer, 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT ID_buyer, 
                   SUM( total_orders ) as total_orders,
                   SUM( total_itens ) as total_itens
     FROM public.store1
     GROUP BY ID_buyer ) gb_store1 ON gb_store1.id_buyer = buyer.id ,
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT ID_buyer, 
                   SUM( total_orders ) as total_orders,
                   SUM( total_itens ) as total_itens
     FROM public.store2
     GROUP BY ID_buyer ) gb_store2 ON gb_store2.id_buyer = buyer.id ,
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT ID_buyer, 
                   SUM( total_orders ) as total_orders,
                   SUM( total_itens ) as total_itens
     FROM public.store3
     GROUP BY ID_buyer ) gb_store3 ON gb_store3.id_buyer = buyer.id ;
```

So, this query has a couple elements should focus on. The subselects/groupby allow you to total within your subtables by ID_buyer. The LEFT OUTER JOIN make its so your query can still return a result, even if a subselect finds no matching record. Finally, the COALESCE allows you to return 0 when one of your totals is NULL (because the subselect found no match).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! I was working on a solution by connecting Ruby to PostgreSQL, but yours is better and faster. I did not know the COALESCE function! Thank you once more!

Comment: No problem, Alex!